# How can I perform an actual count query on a Realm List collection?

Tags: ios, swift, realm, nspredicate

This particular use case is lacking detail in the [Realm docs](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/api/Classes/List.html), and Apple's NSPredicate reference is a nightmare for someone unfamiliar with the syntax. As a result, I've ended up with a bunch of interconnected questions.

1. The `filter()` and `index()` methods for Realm Lists have two variants, with one using `NSPredicate` while the other uses a string predicate: am I right to deduce from the GitHub page that the string predicate version is just a wrapper and uses `NSPredicate` syntax as well?
2. How can I perform a count query and actually get the number of entries that match a condition rather than a `Results` collection of objects that match said condition? Is this even possible? And is it even necessary?
3. Does using `filter()` to get a `Results` collection of objects actually tax system resources, or does the lazy nature of the references mean that getting the `Results` collection and then checking its `.count` is equivalent to an actual count query (a la SQL)?
4. What do I do if `filter()` isn't enough and I need to use Swift's `map()` or `reduce()` on a particular property in a Realm List collection? Is that even possible?

Basically, most of my problems are stemming from trying to work with properties of the objects stored in a Realm List rather than with the objects themselves, i.e. count **how many** objects in the List have a property set to a certain value, several times for different values, then figure out which of the counts is higher -- never actually retrieving any values to use directly.

Answer (score 1):

1. There are 3 variants: Predicate, String (which wraps predicate) and a closure, which you shouldn't use unless you really need it because it decays into an array and prevents optimizations in the db query since it has to hand your closure all of the results.
2. Realm supports the NSPredicate aggregate functions including @count. See the [documentation](https://academy.realm.io/posts/nspredicate-cheatsheet/).
3. Results is indeed lazy and the count can be optimized.  For instance if you are querying an index field then it can just look at the number of indices and does not have to pull all of the records.
4. You can always decay results into a swift array with `Array(results)`.  In that case the values are copied eagerly and you no longer have a lazy autoupdating set of Results.  You can then do anything you can do with a regular Array or Sequence, such as `filter`, `map`, `reduce`, `index`, `first` etc.